# Scons appears to ignore CPPPATH value

Tags: scons

I set the CPPPATH variable via ParseFlags:

```
env = Environment()
env["CXX"] = "clang++" 
d = env.ParseFlags("-I. -I../utl")
print d
env.StaticLibrary(target="myLib",source = source_files)
```

The print of d shows CPPPATH set to the correct directory:

> {'CPPFLAGS': [], 'FRAMEWORKPATH': [], 'LIBPATH': [], 'CXXFLAGS': [],
>   'LIBS': [], 'ASFLAGS': [], 'LINKFLAGS': [], 'RPATH': [], 'CPPDEFINES':
>   [], 'FRAMEWORKS': [], 'CCFLAGS': [], 'CFLAGS': [], 'CPPPATH': ['.',
>   '../utl']}

However, the compile output has no -I option:

```
clang++ -o ABC_Exception.o -c ABC_Exception.cpp
```

And fails to find an include file in ../utl

> ./ABC_Exception.hpp:4:10: fatal error: 'Exception.hpp' file not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*ParseFlags* should be followed by *MergeFlags* to add the variables to the environment as described in the [SCons documentation](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#sect-parseflags).

> ParseFlags returns a dictionary containing the options distributed
>   into their respective construction variables. Normally, this
>   dictionary would be passed to MergeFlags to merge the options into a
>   construction environment, but the dictionary can be edited if desired
>   to provide additional functionality. (Note that if the flags are not
>   going to be edited, calling MergeFlags with the options directly will
>   avoid an additional step.)

In your example, you can simply call MergeFlags with the string passed to ParseFlags.